# Can't get second input (Java)

Tags: java, input

```
public void hesapEkle() {
    System.out.println("Oluşturmak istediğiniz hesap türünü seçiniz:");
    System.out.println("1. Vadeli Hesap");
    System.out.println("2. Vadesiz Hesap");
    Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int acilacakHesapTuru = getInput.nextInt();
    getInput.close();

    String hesapTuru;
    System.out.println("Hesap turu girin (Maas / Normal):");

    Scanner getInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    hesapTuru = getInput1.nextLine();
    getInput1.close();

    if((hesapTuru != "Maas") && (hesapTuru != "Normal")) {
        System.out.println("Girilen hesap turu gecersiz oldugundan normal hesap olarak tanimlandi.");
        hesapTuru = "Normal";
    }
}
```

Hesap turu girin (Maas / Normal)

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at Musteri.hesapEkle(Musteri.java:65)

Here is my output^^ Why can't i get another input except acilacakHesapTuru variable?
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: full output:

```[code block]Olusturmak istediginiz hesap turunu seciniz:
1. Vadeli Hesap
2. Vadesiz Hesap
2
Hesap turu girin (Maas / Normal)

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at Musteri.hesapEkle(Musteri.java:65)
at Proje.main(Proje.java:7)
```

Comment: `getInput.close();` you've closed the scanner, which will in turn close `System.in`, which is not something you want to do

Comment: `hesapTuru != "Maas"` is not how you compare `String`s in Java see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for  how it should be done

Comment: After `getInput.nextInt()`, add `getInput.nextLine();`, this will consume the dangling new line, so that when you do `hesapTuru = getInput.nextLine();` it won't return immediately (with an empty `String`)

Comment: i changed .nextLine(); to .next(); and it fixed. Thx for everyone.

Comment: But i have another question now.
```[code block]
 public static long createIBAN() {  //Rastgele IBAN oluşturma.
        long createdIBAN = 0;

        Random rand = new Random();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            int randNum = rand.nextInt(9)+1;
            createdIBAN += Math.pow(10, i)*randNum;
        }

        return createdIBAN;
    }
```


This method return 0 everytime? Why? It should return 16digits random num

Comment: Just remember, `.next()` will split words on spaces, so if the user enters multiple words, you'll only get the first one

Comment: Returned `2224541622274355` for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer actually its better for me :).

Comment: @MadProgrammer weird, it's still returning 0 for me :/

Comment: We'd need to see it used in context - but that's actually another question

Comment: yeah, but i can't create a new question within 90mins :(

Comment: `super(BankaHesap.createIBAN(), vadeliBakiye, hesapBilgisi, "Vadeli");` i'm using it like that and returns 0 but if i use it except a super tag it returns normal